# wp8: open htm page in webBrowser by button click?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have several html pages in my app. I named those html files as f1.html, f2.html, f3.html, \... f454.html. So, I want to display these files by user preference. So, I have created a textbox and button in `CustomMessageBox` using `NuGet` and an xaml page with the name webview.xaml. If user entered 3 in the textbox, f3.html should be open in webview.xaml.

I don't know how to code. Best answer will much appreciated seriously.

C# Code I did til now [UPDATE];

```
 TextBox getFileNo = new TextBox();
 getFileNo.Height = 72;
 getFileNo.Width = 150;
 getFileNo.MaxLength = 3;
 TextBox getHashNo = new TextBox();
 getHashNo.Height = 72;
 getHashNo.Width = 150;
 getHashNo.MaxLength = 3;

 string showFile;
 showFile = getFileNo.Text;
 string hashId;
 hashId = getHashNo.text;
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/webview.xaml?Page=" + site, UriKind.Relative));
```

In webview.xaml:

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Page"))
        {
            var page = NavigationContext.QueryString["Page"];
            browser.Navigate(new Uri("/f" + page + ".html#" + hashId, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to the *webview.xaml* page passing it querystring with the desired hmtl file:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/webview.xaml?Page={0}&id={1}", showFile, hashId), UriKind.Relative));
```

In your *webview.xaml* page, you can override `OnNavigatedTo` method to check the passed page and open it in web browser:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Page") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("id"))
    {   
        var page = NavigationContext.QueryString["Page"];
        var hashId = NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];

        yourWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/f{0}.html#{1}", page, hashId), UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

See [Passing paramenters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/css#BKMK_PassingParameters) section from [How to perform page navigation on Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: brilliant piece of code. one more doubt. i wanna navigate to `id` declared in my app. for example, `f1.html#34`. how to do this ?

Comment: I guess you can pass it as querystring too: `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/webview.xaml?Page=" + showFile + "&id=" + yourId, UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: but what's not working? it's not opening in the desided id, or you have problem to pass it as parameter to your webview.xaml page? Do you get any error?

Comment: Error in webview.xaml.cs `The name 'hashId' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Ok, that's because you have to read that parameter in your webview.xaml too: `var hashId = NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];`

Comment: thank you so much. your old code works likes a charm than your new code. so i updates this answer with the old code